# How to know the address of the webpage from which <a href="present page"> was clicked?

Tags: asp-classic

I have a login.asp page. Whenever the session expires, the user is given a link to the login page to log in. After logging in, users need to go back to the original page from which the link was clicked. How do I get the address of that webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redirect him to

```
/login.asp?next=url-of-where-the-user-tried-to-go
```

Once he logs in, redirect him to the parameter `next`.  This is extremely common.

Answer (score 2):

You have to grab the `referrer` when the user is redirected to the login page. Store that and redirected the user back after the login process.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property of the document object called `referrer`

For example link to your website was clicked from http://example.com, you can use `document.referrer` to get `http://example.com`

Ref - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp